# How to convert a string representing date into a DateList expression?

Tags: date-and-time

How to convert a string representing date into a DateList expression?  For example, how to turn "1/2/2000" into {2000,1,2} assuming American style, and {2000, 2, 1} assuming European style, respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[dlF]
dlF[ds_String, c : ("US" | "European" | "EU") : "US"] := 
 Module[{conv = Switch[c, "US", {"Month", "Day", "Year"}, _, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}]},
  DateList[{ds, conv}][[;; 3]]]

Through@{dlF, dlF[#, "EU"] &, dlF[#, foo] &}@"1/2/2000"
(* {{2000, 1, 2}, {2000, 2, 1}, dlF["1/2/2000", foo]} *)
```